# Copy Multiple Cell Values in QGIS for Filtering Purposes

Tags: qgis

I have multiple points selected, that I would like to filter out. I can copy each cell value, but that is multiple clicks. Is there a simple way to copy the value of multiple rows from a single column?

Using a simple example, I have selected the following points, I would like to be able to copy 1, 84, 900 so I can filter out those values.

| fid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 84 | AI |
| 900 | PQ |

---

Found a Workable Solution:
Using the Selection as Filter plugin, I selected the features I want to omit, then did an inverse selection based on that. Then used the show 'selected features only' feature of the plugin.

I still feel like it would be useful for users to be able to copy multiple cell values from the attribute table, but this works for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

##### Copy selected field values

If you want to copy indeed the field values of the selected features, use this expression, where `"id"` is the field's name: `array_to_string (array_agg ("id", filter:=is_selected(@feature)))`

##### Filtering selected fields

The apply a filter based on the selected features, simply click on `Show Selected Features` at the bottom of the attribute table:

*Filtering attribute table to only show selected features (click on invert selection to **hide** the selected features):*

[image]

Comment: Where should the expression be typed?

Comment: For example in the field calculator if you want to calculate a new field, based on the values of the selected features, or in Geometry generator.

Comment: I tried this in the query builder for applying a filter, but it didn't work. I'm exploring some parts of the expression though to see if I can find a way. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Instead of `"id"` use a fieldname you have. Difficult to say what's going wrong without have some details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. If your layer contains points and you want to retrieve a selection from the layer, simply select the points and save a new one by checking 'selected objects'  (here in yellow)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, and I've done this in the past. But after a while, it became too difficult to maintain all the various layers. Now I prefer to keep datasets whole and apply filters and notes, rather than continuously create new shapefiles or scratch layers.